# Proving symmetric difference is associative

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove that for $A,B,C \subset X$, we have
$$
(A \Delta B) \Delta C = A \Delta (B \Delta C). 
$$
I tried to prove it by brute force by taking an argument in the left-hand side, but I couldn't do it in a way that every step is reversible. There has to be a "clever" way to do this that I'm just not thinking of, but I'm not able to gain any kind of graphical intuition by plotting venn diagrams to see exactly how to do that.

EDIT: My attempt at brute force:
\begin{align*}
x \in (A \Delta B) \Delta C & \iff x \in ((A \Delta B) - C) \cup (C - (A \Delta B)) \\
& \iff x \in (((A - B) \cup (B -  A)) - C) \cup (C - ((A - B) \cup (B - A)) 
\end{align*}

Comment: Brute force is a reasonable approach here — write out the LHS explicitly as a boolean expression for membership in $(A\Delta B)\Delta C$ in terms of memberships in the individual sets, expand it out into monomials, and note the symmetry of the expression you get.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I've expanded it out, and I do see symmetry in the final line. I'm somewhat inclined to let $D = (A - B) \cup (B - A)$ and continue to try to simplify this, but with slightly less messiness. Is that on the right track?

Comment: +1 for showing your work! I was thinking of a slightly different expanding-out; let me give you a hint of an answer...

Comment: Since you mention trying to gain intuition, I'll just mention that $\Delta$ is related to logical XOR in the same way that $\cap$ is related to AND and $\cup$ to OR. That is, $x\in A\Delta B \iff x\in A \text{ xor } x\in B$. But XOR in turn can be thought of as bitwise addition (mod 2, with no carries); does that give you any ideas about how to interpret $(A\Delta B)\Delta C$?

Answer (score 2):

$\def\sd{\mathop{\Delta}}\def\sm{\mathop\smallsetminus}$

Prove, if you haven't been given, that: $~~~~~X\sd Y= (X\cap Y^\complement)\cup(X^\complement\cap Y)\\(X\sd Y)^\complement = (X^\complement\cap Y^\complement)\cup(X\cap Y)$

Then apply.

$${(A\sd B)\sd C\\=((A\sd B)\cap C^\complement)\cup((A\sd B)^\complement\cap C)\\\vdots\\= ((A\cap B^\complement\cap C^\complement)\cup(A^\complement\cap B\cap C^\complement))\cup((A^\complement\cap B^\complement\cap C)\cup (A\cap B\cap C))\\\vdots\\=A\sd (B\sd C)}$$

Answer (score 1):

For any set $A$, define the function $\mathbb{1}_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $\mathbb{1}_A(x)=0$ if $x\notin A$.

Notice that for any two $A,B\subset X$, $A=B$ if and only if $\mathbb{1}_A=\mathbb{1}_B$.

Since $A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)=B \triangle A$,  we have that
$$\mathbb{1}_{A\triangle B}=|\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B|=\mathbb{1}_A(1-\mathbb{1}_B)+ \mathbb{1}_B(1-\mathbb{1}_A)=\mathbb{1}_A+\mathbb{1}_B-2\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{1}_B$$

Repeated application of these identities yields
\begin{align}
\mathbb{1}_{(A\triangle B)\triangle C}&=\mathbb{1}_{A\triangle B}(1-\mathbb{1}_C)+\mathbb{1}_C(1-\mathbb{1}_{A\triangle B})\\
&=\big(\mathbb{1}_A(1-\mathbb{1}_B)+\mathbb{1}_B(1-\mathbb{1}_A)\big)(1-\mathbb{1}_C)+\mathbb{1}_C\Big(1-\big(\mathbb{1}_A(1-\mathbb{1}_B)+\mathbb{1}_B(1-\mathbb{1}_A)\big)\Big)\\
&=\Big(\mathbb{1}_A(1-\mathbb{1}_B)(1-\mathbb{1}_C)+\mathbb{1}_B(1-\mathbb{1}_A)(1-\mathbb{1}_C)\Big)+\mathbb{1}_C\Big((1-\mathbb{1}_A)(1-\mathbb{1}_B)+\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{1}_B\big)\\
&=\Big(\mathbb{1}_A(1-\mathbb{1}_B)(1-\mathbb{1}_C)+\mathbb{1}_B(1-\mathbb{1}_A)(1-\mathbb{1}_C)+\mathbb{1}_C(1-\mathbb{1}_A)(1-\mathbb{1}_B)\Big)+\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{1}_B\mathbb{1}_C
\end{align}
A similar procedure gives
$$\mathbb{1}_{A\triangle(B\triangle C)}=\Big(\mathbb{1}_A(1-\mathbb{1}_B)(1-\mathbb{1}_C)+\mathbb{1}_B(1-\mathbb{1}_A)(1-\mathbb{1}_C)+\mathbb{1}_C(1-\mathbb{1}_A)(1-\mathbb{1}_B)\Big)+\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{1}_B\mathbb{1}_C$$

Hence, $A\triangle(B\triangle C)=(A\triangle B)\triangle C$.

Answer (score 0):

So to save some space, I'm going to write $a$ for the proposition $x\in A$; similarly $b$ and $c$. Then saying that $x\in A\Delta B$ is saying $(a\wedge\neg b)\vee(b\wedge\neg a)$. Seen this way, $x\in(A\Delta B)\Delta C$ can be written as $\biggl(\bigl((a\wedge\neg b)\vee(b\wedge\neg a)\bigr)\wedge\neg c\biggr)\vee\biggl(c\wedge\neg\bigl((a\wedge\neg b)\vee(b\wedge\neg a)\bigr)\biggr)$. Now, this is a mess, but if you expand it out into an or of individual 'atoms' of the form $a\wedge(\neg b)\wedge(\neg c)$, etc, using the deMorgan rules, then you should see a much more symmetric expression — in particular, one that's invariant under permutations of $a,b,c$ (or $A,B,C$). Can you see why that's enough to conclude?